# Convert 5A2B4C11G string to [(5,"A"),(2,"B"),(4,"C"),(11,"G")] in Python

Tags: python, run-length-encoding

The title pretty much says it all. I have a small run-length decoding script:

```
def RLdecode(characterList):
    decodedString = ""
    for character, count in characterList:
        decodedString += character.upper() * count
    return decodedString
```

That script requires a list (or whatever this is) that looks like:

```
[(5,"A"),(2,"B"),(4,"C"),(11,"G")]
```

But in order to make it more user-friendly, I want the user to be able to input a string like this:

```
"5A2B4C11G"
```

How would I convert a string like the one above into a list readable by my script? Also, sorry that the title of the question is very specific, but I don't know what the process is called :\

Comment: What about numbers smaller than 2 or greater than 9 ?

Comment: @moooeeeep My program just uses 10G or 64E, but thanks for raising this to my attention, because the solution from Kaushik NP now isn't suitable for my project!

Comment: re.sub(r'(\d+)(\D)', lambda m: m.group(2) * int(m.group(1)),text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**using `itertools.groupby`:**

There's a nice way to do the letter/digit grouping using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
a="5A2B4C11G"
result = [("".join(v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(a,str.isdigit)]
```

that returns `['5', 'A', '2', 'B', '4', 'C', '11', 'G']`

Unfortunately, it flattens the number/letter tuple, so more work is required. Note that applying Kaushik solution to that input gives expected result now that the number/letter is properly done:

```
[(int(result[i]),result[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(result),2)]
```

result:

```
[(5, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (4, 'C'), (11, 'G')]
```

**using regexes:**

Anyway, in that case, regular expressions are well suited to extract the patterns with the required hierarchy.

Just match the string using 1 or more digits + a letter, and convert the obtained tuples to match the (integer, string) format, using a list comprehension to do so, in one line.

```
import re
a="5A2B4C11G"

result = [(int(i),v) for i,v in re.findall('(\d+)([A-Z])',a)]

print(result)
```

gives:

```
[(5, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (4, 'C'), (11, 'G')]
```

Comment: Works. +1 . Am gonna redirect my answer to this.

Comment: Awesome! I used the last solution and it works flawlessly! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `list comprehension` :

```
#s is the string
[(int(s[i]),s[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(s),2)]
```

#driver values

```
IN : s="5A2B4C"
OUT : [(5, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (4, 'C')]
```

Here `range(0,len(s),2)` gives values as : `[0, 2, 4]` which we use to go through the `string`.

**NOTE :** this ofcourse only works with strings of `even` size and with numbers below 10.

**EDIT :** As for numbers with double digits, the answer by [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46511065/7550472) works well.

Comment: make it `[(int(s[i]),s[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(s),2)]` to match OP expected output.

Comment: Thanks. Oversaw that one.

Comment: As I commented on the main post, this does not work with values above 9, so would not be suitable for my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex if you want:

> In one line

```
sorted_list=[i for i in re.findall(pattern, a, re.M)]
```

Same approach :

```
import re
a="5A2B4C"

pattern=r'(\d)(\w)'
list=[]
art=re.findall(pattern,a,re.M)

for i in art:
    list.append(i)

print(list)
```

For your new edited problem here is my new solution :

```
import re

a = "5A2B4C11G"

pattern = r'([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z])'
list = []
art = re.findall(pattern, a, re.M)

for i in art:
    list.append(i)

print(list)
```

> Output:

```
[('5', 'A'), ('2', 'B'), ('4', 'C'), ('11', 'G')]
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , it was misprint, i was correcting meantime you commented :)

Comment: that said, the solution looks promising but needs rework.

Comment: you don't need to create a list with `art`: it's already a list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah need little more accuracy in regex (in case string contain space or anything ) but for this problem, it will work i think.

Comment: This seems a little over-complicated for me, and it still doesn't work with values above 9! :(

Comment: @YasathDias You should add more explanation  in your question , please read your question , it says `Convert 5A2B4C string to [(5,“A”),(2,“B”),(4,“C”)] in Python`

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul You're right, I've changed it now :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no its not list , its gave tuple that's  why i use list.

Comment: @YasathDias I have modified my answer according to your new problem, Please check.

Comment: better, but you still don't need the loop, and the numbers need integer conversion.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i also given list comprehension where no need for list.

Answer (score 1):

You have already got the answer from [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46511065/7550472).
The process is call length decoding.

The whole process can be done in one liner by following code.

```
from re import sub
text = "5A2B4C11G"
sub(r'(\d+)(\D)', lambda m: m.group(2) * int(m.group(1)),text)

OUTPUT : 'AAAAABBCCCCGGGGGGGGGGG'
```

**NOTE** This is not the answer but just an optimization idea for the OP as answer is already present in [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46511065/7550472)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

str = "5A2B4C11G"

pattern = r"(\d+)(\D)"                        # group1: digit(s), group2: non-digit
substitution = r"\1,\2 "                      # "ditits,nondigit "

temp = re.sub(pattern, substitution, str)     # gives "5,A 2,B 4,C 11,G "
temp = temp.split()                           # gives ['5,A', '2,B', '4,C', '11,G']
result = [el.split(",") for el in temp]       # gives [['5', 'A'], ['2', 'B'],
                                              #       ['4', 'C'], ['11', 'G']] - see note
```

---

First we replace sequences of `digits` followed by a `symbol` to something to which we can apply 2-level `split()`, choosing *2 different delimiters* in the replacement string `r"\1,\2 "`

- `space` for the 1<sup>st</sup> level (outer) split(), and
- `,` for the 2<sup>nd</sup> level one (inner).

Then we apply those 2 splits.

**Note:** If you have a significant reason to obtain `tuples` (instead of good enough inner `lists`), simply apply the `tuple()` function in the last statement:

```
     result = [tuple(el.split(",")) for el in temp]
```